24.04 upgrade will only boot into unity
This has been a long running problem over several versions of ubuntu desktop but I hoped upgrade to 24.04 might fix it.  Problem is something to do with Wayland and NVIDIA drivers!  So my actual question is where might I go to get some suggestions how to fix graphical / wayland stuff on new install?
Currently when it attempts to boot to wayland, get error message "something has gone wrong, reboot" and it will only continue using Unity.
PC is Dell 7810 with an ASUS NVidia 1660i graphics card, now running updated NVidia 550 drivers.  Any suggestions most welcome.  Thx. J.

Do you mean 'X' as opposite to 'Wayland', when you write 'Unity'? Or otherwise, what would you expect instead of Unity? Which flavour of Ubuntu are you upgrading (standard Ubuntu Desktop or some community flavour)? Which was the original version of Ubuntu (16.04 LTS, 18.04 LTS, 20.04 LTS or 22.04 LTS or one of the shortlife versions)?

thx @sudodus.  It has been an ongoing problem with 22.04, 22.10, 23.04 and 23.10.  Now with 24.04 installed I get three choices at login 1) GNOME CLASSIC (Xorg I presume?), 2) Ubuntu (wayland I think), or 3) Unity.  Only one that does not return a message "Oh no! Something has gone wrong " ...  is Unity.  I would like to get 2) wayland to work properly.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31213773/how-to-start-gnome-wayland-session-from-command-line-tty] Here I found a work around!  If, at boot, I open a new terminal Cntl-Alt-F3, and login, then type "XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland dbus-run-session gnome-session" it starts a wayland graphical session!  Why can't it do this at boot/login?

Version 24.04 LTS is new, and I think you have found a bug, maybe specific for your hardware. Please report a bug at Launchpad.

Thx @sudodus, I will try that.  At present can not login to lauchpad!  Silly errors, appears ubuntu sso is dodgy?
